# Formatting a Crystal Report datetime field to date in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a report, and when it runs, it pulls a date. When the date is displayed on the report, it is displayed like:

`11/20/2012 12:00:00AM`

I'd like it to be displayed like:

`11/20/2012`

When trying to edit the formula in the Format Formula Editor, I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this formula:

```
ToText(Cdate({tbl_R002.Date}))
```

Comment: CDate only allows number, string, or dateTime parameters types in the form you gave so I guess crystal interpreted `{tbl_R002.Date}` as one of those types and not a Date type.

Answer (score 2):

This one Works perfect in almost any case:

```
ToText(Cdate({Command.Payment Date}),"dd/MMM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field is a DateTime you need to use the ToText function for this, i.e.

```
ToText({tablename.fieldname}, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @penfold, but when trying your suggestion, I am getting an error: `Too many arguments have been given to this function.` and then the `"MM/dd/YYYY"` portion of the formula is highlighted. My formula looks like: `ToText({tbl_R002.Date}, "MM/dd/YYYY")`.

Comment: What type is `{tbl_R002.Date}`?

Comment: This report is querying a DB2 database, the field data type is DATE. When running this report manually, I correctly return back a date.

Comment: Can you try making a Formula Field with the above? It could be because you are using a formatting formula, though I've tested it and it worked in Crystal V.10. Also my format string was wrong YYYY should be yyyy.

Comment: I'm not sure if I know how to do what you are asking. Another note: when hovering over the `Date` field in design view, it's saying the field is a `String`. Would have have anything to do with it?